# __webpack_require__(...).native is not a function

Tags: webpack

Use webpack. The application compile successfully, but in browser float error:

"Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).native is not a function".

Browser indicate on string "BSON = require('bson').native().BSON" from mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js (install with mongodb).

My webpack comman config file:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './client/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './client/vendor.ts',
        'client': './client/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.json']
    },

    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('client', 'component'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('client', 'component'),
                loader: 'raw'
            },

            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                loader: "imports?jQuery=jquery"
            }
        ]
    },

    node: {
        fs: "empty",
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        module: 'empty'
    },
    
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['client', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
            // template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

Dev config:

```js
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    // devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devtool: "source-map",

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

If need somethink else, I can provide it. Thanks.